# Метод для возвращения только Приватных полей Java Reflextion

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток подскажите пожалуйста есть ли метод в рефлексии который возвращает только приватные поля в Java Рефлексия 
На подобие 
.getDeclaredFields(); возвращает все поля, а нужно только приватные

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте модификатор с помощью [Modifier.isPrivate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isPrivate-int-).

```
Field[] fields = someObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
  if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
     System.out.println(field.getName()+" is private");
  }
}
```